# Unhandled promise rejection in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a warning of unhandled promise rejection and undefined is not an object evaluating to this.state.gridData[0].brand

there is something wrong with this part of the code

```js
async componentDidMount() {
       const bikes = await fetchVehicleBasedOnType(VEHICLE_TYPES.TWO_WHEELER);
       this.setState({ bikes });
       const gridData = _.uniqBy(bikes, 'brand').map((K) => {
                return { brand: K.brand, logo: K.brand_logo };
                              });
       this.setState({ gridData,
                       selectedBikeBrand: this.state.gridData[0].brand,
                       selectedBikeBrandLogo: this.state.gridData[0].logo,
                       loading: false
                      });
        const listData = bikes
        .filter(item => item.brand === this.selectedBrand)
        .map(({ model, image }) => ({ model, modellogo: image }));
        this.setState({ listData });
  }
```

can someone suggests the edits and fixes to make this code better..

Comment: You misspelled `gridData`.

Comment: I have corrected it and still I have the same issue @JLRishe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not assigning `gridData` to `this.state`, so presumably `this.state.gridData` is `undefined`. Just remove the usage of `this.state`.
You should also check to make sure that `gridData` isn't empty before trying to access properties on `gridData[0]`.

```
const gridData = _.uniqBy(bikes, 'brand').map((K) => {
    return { brand: K.brand, logo: K.brand_logo };
});

const firstItem = gridData[0] || { };

this.setState({ 
    gridData,
    selectedBikeBrand: firstItem.brand,
    selectedBikeBrandLogo: firstItem.logo,
    loading: false
});
```

Comment: I did the same for Listdata I some issues can u pls look at this link 

[https://jsfiddle.net/uw0nhh23/](https://jsfiddle.net/uw0nhh23/)

Comment: @nadeshoki I'm pretty sure that `this.selectedBrand` doesn't refer to anything. Try using `firstBrandItem.brand` instead.

Comment: I did that have still having the same issue 

pls have a look here: [https://jsfiddle.net/vn9eouuu/](https://jsfiddle.net/vn9eouuu/)

Comment: @nadeshoki What same issue? You haven't said what the issue is.

Comment: thanks a ton it was the same mistakes its working now thanks again for helping

Comment: can u help with this : [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152173/how-can-i-automatically-load-data-in-the-a-custom-picker-while-one-of-the-picker)

Answer (score 0):

You have girdData[0].brand when you are setting the state.

Comment: So where should I give it can u suggest how to

Comment: Give what?  I am afraid I don't follow.

Comment: I need to assign the selectedBikeBrand as gidData[0].Brand so how else should I do pls suggest that